# 3 htaccess protection rules on 3 different environments

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to protect different par of my website depending on the environment I'm working on.
I have three different environments:

- localhost : protect nothing
- www.test.example.com : protect the whole website (it's a test website so I don't want it to be accessible)
- www.example.com : protect only /admin url (the live website, only /admin is protected)

For now, I use different htaccess files.

For test.example.com, I add:

```
AuthUserFile mypasswordfile
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter password"
require valid-user
```

For example.com, I add:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /admin/? auth=1
AuthUserFile mypasswordfile
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter a password"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=!auth
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

Is there a way to use only one htacess with condition to have something like

```
if(localhost)         { do nothing }
if(test.example.com)  { require valid user on all domain }
if(example.com)       { require valid user only on /admin}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this combined .htaccess:

```
# require valid user only on /admin
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin(/|$) auth=1
# if(test.example.com)  { require valid user on all domain }
SetEnvIf Host ^test\.example\.com$ auth=1
# if(localhost)         { do nothing }
SetEnvIf Host ^localhost$ !auth

AuthUserFile mypasswordfile
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter a password"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=!auth
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

Comment: I'm being ask the passworkd on localhost. I remove the last setEnvIf (on localhost) and it seems ok. Don't know why

Comment: That's great, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and btw it was really a great question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use version control, for example Mercurial (hg) and add those files to ignore list. This way the .htaccess files will not be overwritten when pushing changes.

Comment: That is really not what I have in mind. I don't want to use a new tool if it is possible to use some conditional syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Apache 2.4+ it has an `<If .. >` Directive you can use : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

So you could read the Apache `SERVER_NAME` and apply conditions accordingly inside your `.htaccess` file.

```
<If "%{SERVER_NAME} =~ /^test\.example\.com/">
  ** require valid user on entire domain **
</If>
<ElseIf "%{SERVER_NAME} =~ /^example\.com/">
  ** require valid user only on /admin **
</ElseIf>
```

You could leave it as that or add in a specific `<ElseIf>` for 'localhost' with a final `<Else>` containing 'Deny from all' or similar - just to make sure you don't leave it open if you upload onto another development environment.

Note: you could also use `SERVER_ADDR` instead of `SERVER_NAME` and identify the server by IP address - which might be more reliable.